# Why do lines with "c-n-f Metadata" appear in the output of `sudo apt update`?

Tags: apt, updates

Kubuntu 19.10

I can't say when this began, but the output of `sudo apt update`
 has lines with `c-n-f Metadata`.

```
...                                                       
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu eoan InRelease                                                  
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [232 B]               
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security/universe amd64 Packages [2,404 B]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [288 B]
Fetched 445 kB in 2s (195 kB/s)                         
Reading package lists... Done
...
```

I found  [please add cnf support to debmirror](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debmirror/+bug/1821251) indicating that `cnf` expands to "Command not found" but after reading that I'm none the wiser in understanding its purpose in `sudo apt update`. What is it's purpose?

Comment: Ever wondered when you try to run a command that doesn't have any binary/file/application to invoke, it suggests the package which contains that command, for example: `Command 'mono' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install mono-runtime`, how does that happen?

Comment: @Kulfy, IIRC, command not found used to work even prior to the appearance of cnf metadata in `sudo apt update`.

Comment: Indeed. But apt used to look into Contents-$arch to find the package which used to be in MBs but now it looks in cnf which is in KB. Thus improving response time.

Comment: Was that always the job of `apt`? Was `apt` looking at available commands?

Comment: If the command fails and returns command-not-found, then only apt search for that (AFAIK).  As of now I don't know the exact implementation, thus not written the answer.

Comment: No hurry, but I'm not seeing the connection between running a command, getting the response, `command not found` and `apt`. AFAICT, the appearance of the `c-n-f Metadata` entry in `sudo apt update` isn't triggered by my running a non-existent command.

Comment: cnf Metadata is a file located in `/var/lib/apt/lists`. It's separate for main, universe, restricted and multiverse. There was no cnf Metadata in releases before 18.10. It started after 19.04. Moreover, I find it little odd that you mentioned that you are using 18.04 but the output suggests you are using 19.10. And I believe that's why it is fetching that metadata. Or if you really using Eoan, it might have found an "update" in that file.

Comment: @Kulfy Would you mind aggregating your comments into an answer? :)

Comment: Take a look in your /etc/apt/sources.list. If there is also a c-n-f it is normal that this appears for apt

Comment: @Kulfy just remind if you want to put that comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The Ubuntu (21.04) package [command-not-found](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/command-not-found) contains `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50command-not-found` which makes [apt(8)](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/man8/apt.8.html) check for the `c-n-f Metadata` entries in the repositories when updating.

If this is installed, [bash(1)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/bash) & [zsh(1)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/zsh) shells will produce a suggestion along with the error message for missing commands, e.g.:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ rogue
Command 'rogue' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install bsdgames-nonfree
user@ubuntu:~$
```

Ubuntu's [bash(1)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/bash) global config file `/etc/bash.bashrc` checks for `command-not-found` and loads handler routines for it if present.

The downloaded commands are stored in `/var/lib/apt/lists/*_cnf_Commands` (as mentioned by [kulfy](https://askubuntu.com/users/816190/kulfy))
The aggregated data is stored in `/var/lib/command-not-found/` in SQLite/json.